# Why I keep getting Mix manifest not found while integrating ES6 app into a laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, ecmascript-6, npm-scripts

This is the first time trying to integrate an app written in vanilla ES6 into my Laravel Project.
I installed all the dependencies that required by the JS app into my Laravel app and copied the hole src folder into resources/js folder.
when I run `npm run dev` , I get listing directory page instead of running the actual App.js file

[image: listing directory page]

scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./resources/js/app.js",
    "build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack",
    "dev": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base ./resources/js"
},
```

I created a new route that refers to test.blade.php file:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

test.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="{!! mix('js/app.js') !!}" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to enter the new route that I defined `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` I keep getting Mix manifest not found at: path\myproject\public/mix-manifest.json

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .version();
```

webpack.config.babel.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './resources/js/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        query: {
          plugins: ['@babel/transform-runtime'],
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', {loader: 'css-loader'}]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=[path][name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I tried to moving the ES6 files from resources folder to the public folder, I keep getting 'listing directory'.

Expected outcome, when the user clicks on the defined route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` it will run the ES6 app.

Comment: You are never compiling with Laravel Mix, you are literally just using webpack, so when you use `mix(...)` in blade, you have no `mix-manifest.json` at all...

Comment: @matiaslauriti That's right! I don't have mix-manifest,json , What do you suggest to fix the problem, if you need any clarification on any file I used, just ask please. Thank you!

Comment: Change the `webpack` command to `mix` and the webpack dev server command to `mix watch`

Comment: @apokryfos I did it. Now I have this error : Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

Comment: @HusseinMMalkawi always update your original question with that new error you just gave. Your actual question has changed. It's so easy to Google for your error